# how to unbind the click event of parent div when clicked on child div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="addCompaniesModal">
    <div id="addCompany_map"></div>
    <div class="addMarkerBtn"></div>
</div>
```

Hi there when i click on the child  **addCompany_map** the parent  **addCompaniesModal** should not be called ... I have done something like this.. but for some reason it didnt work..and parent div is getting selected on clicking on child  can some one please explain me the solution

```
$(document).on('click','#addCompany_map', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('#addCompaniesModal').click(function(){
});
```

Comment: I've made an update to my answer based on some of your comments, so do check it out..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event propagation is happening from the child elements to parent elements.

It may look like your first line is handling the click on the child div but the way you specified it actually handles the click on the document level (because your selector is `$(document)`) and it only calls the method if it happened on the child div (the `on('click','#addCompany_map'` part). Since the document is parent to `addCompaniesModal` div, it's click handler will fire after the one used on `addCompaniesModal` div.

In order for this to work, you'll need to change the code to this:

```
$('#addCompany_map').click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$('#addCompaniesModal').click(function(){

});
```

---

EDIT:

I've seen in some of your comments that the main reason you're using `$(document).on('click', ...` approach is because you're adding child divs dynamically.

In that case, there are 2 viable approaches to handling your problem.

First approach is for you to also dynamically add child div handler, and unbind upon removal. You could use this approach:

```
function dynamicallyAddChildren(){
  var oldChildDiv = $('#addCompany_map');
  if (oldChildDiv.length > 0)
    oldChildDiv.off('click', handleChildDiv);
  // remove old child if needed and add new child divs
  newChildDiv.on('click', handleChildDiv);
}

function handleChildDiv(e){
  //do something
  e.stopPropagation();
}

$('#addCompaniesModal').click(function(){
});
```

Second approach is to use `$(document).on('click', ...` approach with both child and parent divs like this:

```
$(document).on('click','#addCompany_map', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on('click','#addCompaniesModal', function(){
});​
```

Comment: Hi Ivan thanks for the reply i tried your second approach its the same ...... can you make your first approach bit more clear.... Thank You

Comment: The approach is based on dynamically adding the click handler upon creation of child div. The function `handleChildDiv(e)` is a  function you're currently using for `addCompany_map` click event. It is explicitly defined so you can both bind and unbind click event.

Function `dynamicallyAddChildren` is just to show how you might use this - when you create `addCompany_map` div you should call `$('#addCompany_map').on('click', handleChildDiv);`. If you're removing that div from it's parent anywhere in the code, you should unbind the event with `$('#addCompany_map').off('click', handleChildDiv);`

Comment: I've created this fiddle so you can see this more clearly - http://jsfiddle.net/fera/HPmyM/. You can use `Add div` button to dynamically add your divs and `Remove div` button to remove them..

Comment: THanks for you effort ivan... its working ...... +1 for your explanation.... cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think:

```
$("#addCompany_map").click(function(){
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a click event on `#addCompaniesModal`, which includes `#addCompany_map`. Therefore by clicking on the child you're also going to click on the parent.

It seems you need to ask yourself what you want to accomplish here. I would remove the click event on the parent if you want something specific to happen to the child inside the parent. If you want to have a click event on another object inside the parent that isn't `#addCompany_map`, such as `.addMarkerBtn`, then do that. But the way you have it above won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use **delegation** and check for the **target element** . That should solve your problem..

That way you can handle all the three div click events in a single handler..

```
$('body').on('click','#addCompaniesModal',function(e) {

    if (e.target.id === 'addCompany_map') {
        alert('Clicked Map Div !!')
    }
    else if (e.target.className === 'addMarkerBtn') {
        alert('Clicked Marker Div !!')
    }
    else {
        alert('Parent Div !!')
    }
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/7sBcA/1/)**

Comment: Hi there i tried you approach but it didnt work because my addCompany_map and addMarkerBtn are dynamically added.....

Comment: where ever i click its going to else case ...may be because ...my child divs are added dynamically...

Answer (score 0):

Use this expression as the simplest solution for your issue:

```
$('#addCompaniesModal').on('click','div', function (e) {
    console.log(e.target.id || e.target.className);
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This also improves the performance, as the [reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/) says: *try to avoid excessive use of document or document.body for delegated events on large documents*. You're killing 2 birds with one stone thus.

Second expression can can stay as is:

```
$('#addCompaniesModal').click(function(){
});
```

[By the way](http://api.jquery.com/click/): `.click(handler)` is a shortcut of `.on("click", handler)`.